# Past tense equivalent of "will do"

Tags: politeness, email

I suffer from spending inordinate amounts of time on email.  Once in a while I get an email that I can respond to succinctly by saying, "Thanks for the suggestion -- will do."

Suppose I respond to the email *after* carrying out the person's suggestion.  Is there something a little less terse than "Thanks for the suggestion -- done"?

Comment: "I've taken care of it" is a little friendlier.  Or "I did what you said and it worked great!"  Every response does not need to come from some list.

Comment: True. However, consider that you don't need a past tense for _Will do!_; you don't have to convert it to indirect speech, after all, any more than you do any other interjection. Just quote them directly: _He said "Ouch!"/"Will do!"_, but not, of course, **He said that ouch.*

Comment: Done is fine. I use it all the time to answer emails that request an action on my part.

Comment: "I've taken care of it" sounds lovely.  Could you put it in an answer so I can mark this resolved?  Thank you.

Comment: Agreeing with Steven. My own feeling is that "done" is just as terse as "will do," but also just as friendly.

Comment: Thank you both for the reassurance, Jason and Steven.  I will try to get up my courage to do that.  Women are in general expected to be more verbose in email than men, especially when they're writing to another woman. - - -  I still like "I've taken care of it" best but @HotLicks hasn't put it in an answer.  I wonder if I should do that for him/her?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Suggestion accepted, completed. Thanks" - This could be a little less terse than your "Thanks for the suggestion -- done" (4 words, instead of five!)

Comment: I guess you mean "a little less terse". It sounds pretty good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might try "done and done"; it's an idiomatic expression meaning "unambiguously complete", and has a connotation of agreeableness, which lightens its feeling.

If you haven't actually completed the action yet, but are certain you will, you can say "consider it done".

Comment: Maybe that's a Britishism.  I've never heard that in the U.S., so I think I better stay away from it for efficient email.  But thanks.